# PHP Mail class - Including a html file as body

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

Is it possible to include a html document as "message" in the php mailer class?

My html file has only the mail included and I want to send a mail with this content. If it is possible to load this content into the php mail class, then how it is possible without any output in the browser. If I do `file_get_contents()` it's automaticly showing the content of the html file in the browser.

Thanks for help.

Comment: have you tried assigning `file_get_contents()` into a variable?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Do this:

```
$mail->Body = file_get_contents('path/to/file.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the contents of a file with `file_get_contents()`, it's like to use a filestream.

[Here are informations about the function from PHP.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

**Notice** if you like to use HTML in the mailbody, you must say that in the mailheader.